# How can I store a variable in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, variables

I am trying to connect a "serial-code" or whatever to variable to be printed as a string. The code will be generated from 5 sensors and will give me a 5 digit number (sensorValue)(this calculation is not included in the example and I have simplified it to 3 digits). I add an "s" before the code so that I can make a variable with the same name. However I cannot seem to store a variable in the array as I get the message that the variables are assigned but is never used. It clearly cannot be attached the way i'm doing it at least. But I hope that I illustrates what I intend to do.

So I get the "serial-code" s123 but I need to convert it to another string. There will be approximately 3000 different "serial-codes" with a string attached to each one of them. I'm sure I can make 3000 "if" statements but I am afraid that would be very slow.

Any ideas how I can overcome this issue of mine?

Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestingArray
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Trying to assign a value to the string that is used in the array
            var s123 = "Hello";
            var s321 = "Bye";
            var s111 = "Thanks";
            // Creating the array to be used
            object [] arr = { "s123", "s321", "s111" };

            // A simulation of what the future sensor would read
            int sensorValue;
            sensorValue = 123;
            // Creating a "code" with the sensorValue to find it in the array. 
            string doThis = "s" + sensorValue
                ;
            // I want to display the string which corresponds to this "serial-code" string.
            Console.Write(arr.Contains(doThis));
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want a dictionary. The key is the name and the value is the sensor data.

Comment: Do you want to hold onto the value of the variable or the variable itself?  (Do you need to be able to change the value of the variable called `s123` given just a string `s123`?)  In which case, maybe storing them in local variables in the first place is a bad choice.  Maybe the dictionary should be the official place to store such things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want a dictionary. The key is the name and the value is the sensor data.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> sensors = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"s123", "Hello"},
        {"s321", "Bye"},
        {"s111", "Thanks"}
     };

    // A simulation of what the future sensor would read
    int sensorValue;
    sensorValue = 123;
    // Creating a "code" with the sensorValue to find it in the array. 
    string doThis = "s" + sensorValue;

    if (sensors.ContainsKey(doThis)) {
         Console.WriteLine(sensors[doThis]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks alot! :D

Comment: Might want to consider using `string doThis = $"s{sensorValue}";` to take advantage of interpolated strings.